# Godoc stylesheet and javascript

Tags: go

I know Godoc -html generates HTML only without stylesheets and javascript, but once generated where can I get those from?

I got css and js from godoc.org but it seems the js doesn't work with the html markup that is generated by `godoc`

I just want to try this out without using `godoc server`

Example markup:

```
<div id="pkg-overview" class="toggleVisible">
    <div class="collapsed">
        <h2 class="toggleButton" title="Click to show Overview section">Overview ▹</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="expanded">
        <h2 class="toggleButton" title="Click to hide Overview section">Overview ▾</h2>
        <p>Hello World
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Reading the source code usually is the way to go: https://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/?repo=tools#hg%2Fgodoc

Comment: To get toggle working with correct js. At the moment above HTML shows as is without toggle

Comment: @DewyBroto I'm trying to use this HTML for my documentation and view it correctly on browser. CSS seems fine but JS doesn't seem to do things like accordions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try and have a look in [`tools#hg/godoc/static`](http://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/?repo=tools#hg%2Fgodoc%2Fstatic)

You will find a [`godoc/static/godocs.js`](http://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/godoc/static/godocs.js?repo=tools) which might help.

It is used by [`godoc/static/godoc.html`](http://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/godoc/static/godoc.html?repo=tools) anyway.
`godoc.html` also uses:

- [`godoc/static/style.css`](http://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/godoc/static/style.css?repo=tools)
- [`godoc/static/jquery.treeview.css`](http://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/godoc/static/jquery.treeview.css?repo=tools)

Comment: godocs.js doesn't seem to do much. I just updated with example markup generated with godoc command in Windows.

Comment: @PassionateDeveloper it probably uses `html/template` somewhere for that.